# Disable all display managers in (systemd based) ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, display-manager

How can I disable all installed display managers in ubuntu (18.10 or later) without removing them? In my case `gdm3` and `sddm` are installed and I tried:

```
sudo systemctl disable sddm -f
sudo systemctl disable gdm3 -f
```

However after reboot `gdm3` started again.

Answer (score 1):

Disable:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user;
reboot;
```

Enable:

```
systemctl set-default graphical;
reboot;
```